# How do I use AWS CodeArtifact with Apache Ivy?

Tags: ivy, aws-codeartifact

I have set up an AWS CodeArtifact repository, and used Maven to publish a jar to it.

I want to use that jar in an Ant task, and I'm trying to use Apache Ivy to download the dependency.

I've successfully used Ivy to download public libraries from the Maven central repository, but I don't know how to add my AWS CodeArtifact repository to Ivy. The official Ivy tutorials are very hard for me to understand.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to switch from Ivy to the Maven Resolver Ant Tasks - much better documented and easier to understand.

I can now load AWS CodeArtifact dependencies from my ant task with something like this (after doing the Maven setup instructions from AWS CodeArtifact). This downloads the Maven resolver jar as part of the process:

```
<property name="maven.install.version" value="1.3.0"/>
<property name="ant.jar.dir" value="${user.home}/.ant/lib"/>
<property name="maven.jar.file" value="${ant.jar.dir}/maven-resolver-ant-tasks.jar"/>

<target name="load-maven-dependencies" depends="init-maven">
    <resolver:resolve>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency coords="group:artifact:version"/>
        </dependencies>
        <path refid="main.classpath" classpath="compile"/>
    </resolver:resolve>
</target>

<target name="init-maven" depends="download-maven">
    <path id="maven.lib.path">
        <fileset dir="${ant.jar.dir}" includes="${maven.jar.file}"/>
    </path>
    <taskdef resource="org/apache/maven/resolver/ant/antlib.xml" uri="antlib:org.apache.maven.resolver.ant" classpathref="maven.lib.path"/>
</target>

<target name="download-maven" unless="offline">
    <mkdir dir="${ant.jar.dir}" />
    <get src="https://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/apache/maven/resolver/maven-resolver-ant-tasks/${maven.install.version}/maven-resolver-ant-tasks-${maven.install.version}-uber.jar" dest="${maven.jar.file}" usetimestamp="true"/>
</target>
```

You can then use main.claspath in your taskdef, like this:

```
<taskdef name="customTask" classname="com.prosc.CustomAntTask" classpathref="main.classpath" />
```

Comment: It turns out this doesn't work either, I was just getting a cached file. Maven tasks for Ant are broken and don't load the settings from ~/.m2/settings.xml, so it's only useful for pulling stuff from the central maven repo, not from custom repositories.