# How do I enable users to install Python artifacts from CodeArtifact?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pip, aws-codebuild, aws-codeartifact

I was able to use CodeBuild to [build a Python package and publish that package to CodeArtifact](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codeartifact/latest/ug/using-python-packages-in-codebuild.html). Now I need to enable users from the outside to install the package via `pip`. Is this approach possible?

According to [Configure clients with the login command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codeartifact/latest/ug/python-configure.html) and [Configure pip without the login command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codeartifact/latest/ug/python-configure-without-pip.html) , I can configure access. In both approaches, an authorization token has to be generated somehow. I suppose, for each unique user, I would have to create some sort of IAM account and manage the permissions and access? Is this understanding correct?

I also ran into [devpi](https://devpi.net/docs/devpi/devpi/latest/%2Bd/index.html), and it has [user management](https://devpi.net/docs/devpi/devpi/latest/+d/userman/devpi_user.html), but I am not sure if these users are to install packages and/or adminstrate the server itself.

It would be nice if somehow, I can give the user some credential, and they can pass that into pip when they install and specify my CodeArtifact repository. Is this possible with CodeArtifact?

A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65083373/how-do-i-use-aws-codeartifact-with-apache-ivy) in regards to Java artifacts has been raised, but without an accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

yes, your users will need to have some sort of IAM user/role so that they can use the AWS CLI to run the `aws codeartifact login` command so that pip configuration can be updated to use your CodeArtifact repository.

The IAM resource will need to be associated with an IAM policy that allows the appropriate [CodeArtifact permissions.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codeartifact/latest/ug/auth-and-access-control-permissions-reference.html)

Comment: This constraint would mean that I have to somehow maintain (CRUD) those IAMs, right? Meaning, it's looking like I'll have to create a tool/interface to manage authenthication/authorization/access etc...